# Why can't I run a batch file to copy files?

Tags: batch-file

I'm just trying to run a simple batch script to copy a file:

`xcopy /s c:\source\document.txt c:\destination`

Nothing is copied, and I get the response:

> 0 File(s) copied

I've done this before and it's worked fine. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Try using `/i` "If in doubt always assume the destination is a folder"

Comment: `/s` means copy this folder and subfolder, but the source is not a folder but file, so its not working. If you remove the `/s`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying paramter `/s`, which means: Copy this folder and subfolders, but your source is a file, not a folder.

Due to `/s`, the source is assumed to be a folder, but it actually is not.

Remove the `/s` paramter, and all should work fine.

If you indeed want to copy that folder AND all subfolders, remove the filename and only specify the folder, followed by *.*

Comment: Thank you but neither option worked. I removed /s and still nothing copied. I removed the filename and still nothing. I added *.* and still nothing.

Comment: The only reason I can think of that it can't copy it, is that something is holding a full lock on the file. Xcopy can't deal with that. robocopy can however.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Robocopy does indeed work, though I've solved my problem now. All the files I was trying to copy were derived from hidden files. I added /h and the files copied!

Answer (score 0):

I determined that all the files I was trying to copy were *hidden files*, so the only way Xcopy will copy them is by adding the /h option, which solved the problem!